# irreducibility of cyclotomic polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $q=7681$ be a prime.
The $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial for $n=512$ is $f=x^{256}+1$. This polynomial is supposed to be irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_q$. However the polynomial factors in the above field. I am pasting the gp/pari script.

q=7681;
f=Mod(1,q)*x^256 + Mod(1,q); 
factor(f);

This returns 256 factors.
For example

[Mod(1, 7681)*x + Mod(7587, 7681) 1],
[Mod(1, 7681)*x + Mod(7619, 7681) 1], ..etc.

I cannot understand this behavior.

Comment: Why do you think this should be irreducible?

Comment: The factorization of cyclotomic polynomials over finite fields is a frequent topic here. You can easily find more information about this by searching the site. For now azimut's (+1) answer will do.

Answer (score 2):

All cyclotomic polynomials are irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, but this is not true for finite fields, in general.

In this particular case, the order $q-1$ of the unit group $\mathbb F_q^\times$ is divisible by $512$, so $\mathbb F_q$ contains $512$th roots of unity and therefore, $X^{512}-1$ (and then also $f$) decomposes into linear factors over $\mathbb F_q$.